# How can i use passport-local-mongoose with a model using local.email

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport-local

Hi i would like to use the passport-local-mongoose plugin but it seems to work only if you have a model in this form, so without social authentification :

```
var Account = new Schema({
    nickname: String,
    birthdate: Date
 });
```

However i also use social authentification, so my model is used like this :

```
var Account = new Schema({
    local: {
        nickname: String,
        email: String,
    facebook: {
        nickname: String,
        email: String,
    }
   ...
 });
```

Is there an option or a strategy i could use, to tell passport-local-mongoose to do the authentification inside the local authentification ?
Thanks very much